# Как отсортировать массив по первому символу элемента, а если он одинаковый, то по второму?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Как отсортировать массив:

[image: текст, выделенный жирным шрифтом]

Чтобы он превратился вот в такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Логика последовательности заключается в том, что сортировка идет по первому символу (по убыванию), а если первые символы одинаковые, то по второму (в порядке алфавита)

Почти получилось реализовать через огромные конструкции и преобразования, но кажется, что нагородил лишнего, хотелось бы посмотреть какие способы, более-менее простые есть

Comment: покажите что "нагородили"

Comment: Если сортировка по убыванию, то разве не должно быть что `2e` быть раньше, чем `2a`. Или тут убывание по цифрам, а по буквам - возрастание?

Comment: Да, убывание по цифрам, возрастание по буквам

Comment: Нагородил - это вытащил элементы с одинаковым первым символом, закинул в новый массив и перевернул. Можно через spread-оператор разложить их в старый массив и получить, то что нужно, но проблема в том, что если будет элемент не '4t', а '1а', то собьется сортировка по первому символу, так как '1a' будет на первом месте, а не на последнем

Answer (score 0):

Ограничение - входной массив содержит только строки, в которых первый символ - цифра, второй - латинская буква:

```
const input = ['4t','2o','2f','2e','2a'];

input.sort((a,b) => {

if(a[0] > b[0]) return -1;
if(a[0] < b[0]) return 1;


// Тут остается вариант когда a[0] === b[0], дальше сравниванием уже второй символ 

return b[1] < a[1] ? 1 : -1;

});

console.log(input); // ['4t', '2a', '2e', '2f', '2o']
```